# Retrieve firebase list data to create a dynamic table

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular-material, angular-material-table

I want to push the values into a array like below when i retrieve values from firebase database

```
 columns: any[];
 this.columns = [
{ columnDef: 'FirstName', header: 'First Name',    cell: (element: any) => `${element.FirstName}` },
{ columnDef: 'LastName', header: 'Last Name',    cell: (element: any) => `${element.LastName}` },
];
```

Here is what i tried so far.........

```
 this.af.list('/datalist', {
 query: {
    limitToLast: 200,
    orderByChild: 'name',
    equalTo: 'spiderman',
    preserveSnapshot: true
  }
 }).subscribe(snapshot=>{
   if(snapshot!=undefined){
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {

    this.columns.push( { columnDef: childSnapshot.heroname, header: childSnapshot.herotitle,    cell: (element: any) => `${element.heroname}` });
    this.displayedColumns = this.columns.map(c => c.columnDef);

    return false;
    });
   }
  });
```

Error with above code is 
Cannot read property 'columns' of undefined

Even though i declared the columns array globally its not recognizing it.

In HTML i want to use like this....

```
   <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns" [cdkColumnDef]="column.columnDef">
    <mat-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef>{{ column.header }}</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let row">{{ column.cell(row) }}</mat-cell>
   </ng-container>
```

Any hint is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It is not recognising the `this` keyword. You may assign it to a variable prior to the function call `self = this` and then use variable `self` inside your subscription.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because of the following code:

```
snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {

this.columns.push( { columnDef: childSnapshot.heroname, header:  childSnapshot.herotitle,    cell: (element: any) => `${element.heroname}` });
this.displayedColumns = this.columns.map(c => c.columnDef);

return false;
});
```

Here `forEach` takes a callback function as it's first parameter, and `this` inside the callback is in a different context and therefore you get that error.

To solve this, you need to use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> An arrow function does not have its own `this`. The this value of the enclosing lexical scope is used; arrow functions follow the normal variable lookup rules. So while searching for `this` which is not present in current scope they end up finding `this` from its enclosing scope.

Basically what it means that `this` inside the arrow function will refer to `this` in which the arrow function was defined, so you will be able to do the following:

```
snaphot.forEach((childSnapshot)=>{

this.columns.push( { columnDef: childSnapshot.heroname, header: childSnapshot.herotitle,    cell: (element: any) => `${element.heroname}` })
this.displayedColumns = this.columns.map(c => c.columnDef);

return false;
});
```